# CSS 3D transforms in Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I'm trying to get an image to revolve into view - see below.

It works in Chrome, but not on Safari, and thus not on an iPad - the image changes, but the rotation effect does not happen. I think it is just a typo, but I simply can't see it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".qcontainer").on("click", function(e) {
  var p = $(this).find(".back").attr("src");
  console.log(p);
  $(this).find(".inner").addClass("rotated");
 });
})
```

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:400px;
}

.qcontainer {
    position: absolute;
    perspective: 800px;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
}

.inner.rotated {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.inner .face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
    border: 2px solid white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="qcontainer" style="top:5px; left:100px">
        <div class="inner">
            <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/240178989/xmas/img/qmark.png" class="front face" />
            <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/240178989/xmas/img/jona.jpg" class="back face" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use linear transform in your inner class:

```
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear;
 transition: transform 1s linear;
```

I followed this site: http://css3clickchart.com/#3d-transform

here is the fiddle I edited:

http://jsfiddle.net/0evd8mco/5/

I hope this helps you,

greetings Visores